# Run jsp in eclipse on specific port and ssl

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, ssl, https

I have used Eclipse 3.4 to create a Dynamic Web Project.  I have also configured my server to use port 8443 with ssl.  If I start my server I can access my test.jsp by going to it's address

```
  https://localhost:8443/TestContext/test.jsp
```

In eclipse, I have installed this server and added my project to the server.  If I Run test.jsp it always launches as

```
  http://localhost:8080/TestContext/test.jsp
```

My question is: How can I set up eclipse to run this on https://localhost:8443/ rather than the default 8080?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: I posted an answer to modify the port in the server config, but it was completely irrelevant to the question. I deleted it, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @zealot452 any progress on that?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a project called "Servers". There your tomcat should have its folder - for example "Tomcat 6.0.20 at localhost-config". There is `server.xml` there, in which you can enable SSL.

When you enable the SSL, the server *accepts* requests on port 8443 as well as on 8080. The server is not run on a port - it accepts connections on multiple ports. So just type https://localhost:8443/

Comment: "I have also configured my server to use port 8443 with ssl"

I need to know how to run it on that port when I click Run in eclipse